# Iterate through XML nodes / objects and pass to variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell, api

I'd be wanting to iterate through a set of XML and then pass those to variables which can be printed.

Here is an example of the data:

```
<applications>
  <size>75</size>
     <application>
        <name>Applications 1</name>
        <path>/Applications/Utilities/Application 1</path>
        <version>10.14</version>
     </application>
     <application>
        <name>Application 2</name>
        <path>/Applications/Utilities/Application 2</path>
        <version>6.3.9</version>
     </application>
</applications
```

I've looked at using ForEach-Object when trying to output it but to no avail.

```
[string]$applicationProperties = $API.applications.application| ForEach-Object {
    $_.name
    $_.path
    $_.version
}
```

This works but puts them all on one line, I'd like them so they print on individual lines but I couldn't prefix the $_ variable. I'm new to POSH as you can tell.

e.g. so I'd like to have name/path/version data saved to variables

```
[string]$applicationProperties = $API.applications.application | ForEach-Object {
    [string]$name_var = $_.name 
    [string]$path_var = $_.path
    [string]$version_var = $_.variable
}
```

This gives me one "application", but not all the possible objects. Also mentions that even when I'm putting down $name_var it's not accessing that variable? Do I need to do something to access that variable?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The member names in your query `$API.computer.data.properties` doesn't seem to fit with the sample XML you posted? Please post [reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible :) (keep in mind that we cannot see your screen!)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Fixed - tried to anonymise it, somewhat successfully...

Answer (score 0):

When you assign the output from `ForEach-Object` to `[string]$applicationProperties`, you're forcing PowerShell to convert all the strings into a *single* string because of the cast to `[string]`.

What you'll want to do is create a new object for each `application` node that you're iterating over:

```
$appInformation = $API.applications.application | ForEach-Object {
    # Create a new custom objects with the values from the XML nodes
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $_.name 
        Path = $_.path
        Version = $_.version
    }
}
```

Now `$appInformation` will contain an array of objects each with a `Name`, `Path` and `Version` property. You can then further use and/or manipulate these objects in your scripts rather than just having a bunch of strings:

```
$appInformation |ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Here is the version of application '$($_.Name)': $($_.Version)"
}
```

---

If you want to see them printed in the console with each property value on a separate line just pipe the array to `Format-List`:

```bsh
$appInformation |Format-List
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, so to output I'd want to do something like $appInformation.name ?

Comment: `$appInformation.Name` would result in _all the `name` values_ of the objects in the array

Comment: Furthermore Mathias, would it be possible to create a variable / function which would list them all e.g. If I'd want it to go "Name: $($_.name)" and list them all, would that be possible. As I your solution works for writing to terminal, but I'm trying to list to a file where I'm already adding information, maybe a for-loop / for each?

Comment: If you want to produce that as a string: `$appInformation.name |ForEach-Object{ "Name: $($_.Name)"}`, if you just want to show it on screen: `$appInformation |Format-List Name`

Comment: Would it be possible to cast it to another string? E.g. $appInformationName and it'll still loop through? Maybe a function is what I'm looking for, One function which lists name, path and version of each XML node